# Rmd gives memory not mapped when knitting to html

Tags: r, knitr

I am running a Rmd script that combines python and R code through 'reticulate'. I can run the entire code (“Restart R and run All Chunks”) just fine, but when knitting it I often get this bug, that prevents me from knitting the file to html

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0xb8, cause 'memory not mapped'
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
```

For reference, my knit options are:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width  = 12,
                      fig.height = 8,
                      results    = "asis",
                      message    = FALSE,
                      tidy = TRUE,
                      warning    = FALSE
                      )
```

Removing a random part of the script, that can be R chunks, Python chunks, or just markdown text, sometimes fixes the problem and the document compiles. Can anyone give me any suggestions on how to fix this?

Running python `3.7.1`, rstudio `1.2.502`, r-base `3.5.1`.

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.15.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /path/to/conda/env/lib/R/lib/libRblas.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] limma_3.40.0    reticulate_1.15

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1  Matrix_1.2-18   yaml_2.2.1      Rcpp_1.0.4.6    grid_3.5.1      knitr_1.28      jsonlite_1.6.1  xfun_0.13       lattice_0.20-41
```

Comment: Try knitr::opts_chunk$set(error=TRUE) and then try to externally knit rmarkdown::render("yourfile.Rmd") and see if you get more informative error message

Comment: @MDEWITT thanks a lot. I did that, and funnily enough, it works with no error if I run it in R outside Rstudio, but if I do it inside it gives the same error. So while this doesn't answer my question, it actually solves my problem :)

Comment: off note, no error is shown in the Rmd console inside Rstudio either, before the `segfault` error above

Comment: looks like this error can occur when there is an implicit type conversion. If you hand off data between R and python reticulate data types there might be a fault. Weird that it only occurs in interactive sessions though...! Glad there's a work around

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution for this?